# Can you use one hundred percent of IO and CPU at the same time?

Tags: performance

a question that a co-interviewer asked in interviews. I always thought it was a silly question.

Assume single processor and not dual core.

Comment: And what answer does the co-interviewer expect?

Comment: Pretty sure he was expecting a No because the processor would be waiting on the IO or the IO would be waiting on the processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can if DMA is not available. In that case you could end up using the CPU to move data around from I/O to I/O through central memory, if the I/O bandwidth on both devices is high enough you will effectively saturate the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Simple have two processes running, one that uses all CPU, and the other that uses all the I/O it can. This will do it. The real issue is what I/O is being talked about. There are a number of busses in any system, and they all can be bound at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also look for places where IO devices are virtualized and encrypted.  This is probably an unusual case, but not an impossible case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!(Sounds like a cliche right?)
But really, there is such thing as non blocking IO.
You can do a lot of things while you data using up 100% IO.